# CMD Path does not reflect Environmental Variables, reset on change

Tags: java, variables, path, cmd, javac

This is really getting on my nerves.
If I modify my Environmental Variables and click OK, when I try to reopen the Environmental Variables dialogue it shows

```
Windows cannot find %windir%\system32\systempropertiesadvanced.exe
```

This goes away on reboot. However, any variables changed to it are not shown by the CMD when I enter PATH. When I go into my Environmental Variables, it shows the correct ones. If I reopen CMD now, it shows the default variables:

```
PATH=C:\Users\Azmat\AppData\Roaming; C:\Windows
```

Occasionally it recognises java, javac, or even both, but most of the time it doesn't, even when I've changed it. However, IntelliJ and programs which require java and javac work. This leads me to think it's an error with the CMD itself but I don't see how that's possible. Also if it makes any difference sometimes my Windows Explorer file icon goes to the default non-recognised one. My calculator's icon is always like that.

Can anybody help me with this? It's really confusing and I can't find anything else like this on Google. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: See the most helpful answer here: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_vista-hardware/problems-i-faced-with-my-system/d6af1694-4ea8-46b1-879a-196e988ef0a7

Comment: @JamesB, awesome! That made it start recognising javac, which is perfect. However, the first part is still there. Any ideas on what to do?